# HTML and CSS programming

Tags: html, css

I am working with the following code:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <style type="text/css">
    td.one
    {
      align="center";
      colspan="3";
      bgcolor="lightgrey";
      style="font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;"
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="one">Session 1</td>
     <td class="one">Session 1</td>
   </tr>
</body>
```

This CSS is not working for me. I want to make classes so different `<td>` elements will have different appearances.

Comment: HTML and CSS are not programming languages =)

Answer (score 11):

You're using HTML attribute names and syntax in your stylesheet, whereas you need to be using CSS names and syntax:

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            td.one
            {
                text-align: center;
                /* There's no way to do colspan="3" in CSS */
                background-color: lightgrey;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

<body>
  <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
     <td> </td>
     <td> </td>
     <td class="one">Session 1</td>
     <td class="one">Session 1</td>
   </tr>
</body>
```

Comment: The colspan can of course be set in the HTML:

<td class="one" colspan="3">

Answer (score 2):

There's two things wrong with your current code.  First, you're trying to set attributes of `td` with CSS, which isn't possible - you can only change styles.  You have to set the `align`, `colspan` and `bgcolor` attributes inline (though there are CSS equivalents of some of these).

Second, the syntax is incorrect for your CSS rules.  It should look like this:

```
td.one
{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        td.one
        {
            text-align:"Center";
            background-color:Gray;
            font-size:15px;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
     <td> </td>
     <td> </td>
     <td class="one" colspan="3">Session 1</td>
     <td class="one">Session 1</td>
   </tr>
</body>
```